# How to upload the file form client to server if the file length is more than 1 gb?

Tags: javascript, file, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-file-upload, ng-file-upload

I'm facing issue at the time of file upload. If my file size is more than 1gb.

> How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make chunks concept means read 10 or 20 mb from client file and create one file into server then append into this server file until complete.

Chunks mean read 10mb stream from client file and append to serve file up to finish the stream of client file through javascript ajax.